# Ubuntu doesn't boot properly after forced shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome, lightdm

Last night Ubuntu crashed and by pushing the power button on my laptop for 6 seconds I did a force shutdown.
After that Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't boot properly which I guess is because of Gnome.

My system is a  dual boot one, windows and ubuntu 16.04.

When I choose Ubuntu to boot from GRUB I see this picture (As Always):
[The Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jqUI.jpg)

And then screen goes black and after 20 seconds switches back to the logo and again and again...
So I entered the recovery mode from GRUB and removed GDM3 and gnome shell and I reconfigured lightDM with this command:
`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

And nothing changed!
P.S: I can't connect to the Internet from recovery mode's shell (both WiFi and Ethernet). So I can't do any installation with apt...

Answer (score 1):

**Lets first check your file system for errors.**

For 17.10 or older...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Lets check the boot trail...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- select the normal default boot choice
- hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit
- find the string "quiet splash" and change it to ""
- hit <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, or <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue the boot
- observe the screen and note where it stops/hangs
- report back

Comment: I did what you said. The results of this command "sudo fsck -f /" were that the /sda6 is mounted and there was an error. Then after doing editing when boot continued the screen was black and for a second some lines came and again it was black and again those lines were appearing. I got a picture of those lines which is not clear but this is the link -> https://imgur.com/QI8bRiO

Comment: @NimaRa I've updated my answer to include the fsck instructions for 18.04 or higher... so use that method. The boot trail is ok, but I don't think that you captured the last lines on the screen?

Comment: I did that. The result of the second command is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sHYNYH5qfY . After rebooting it shows the logo again and problem is still the same. (It doesn't show those lines anymore and yes I couldn't capture those lines, because it changed to the black screen so fast)

Comment: Try this... using the "check boot trail" in my answer, follow the same steps, but change "quiet splash" to "nomodesert". Using the video cam on your phone, capture the lines you'll see on the screen again. The computer may boot fully with nomodeset enabled. Review the video, and see if you can look at the very end of the video to see what the last lines are, of if anything shows as FAIL.

Comment: The last line is this: "[ OK ] started update UTMP about system runlevel changes.tartup.    Starting Update UTMP about" which looks uncompleted and strange! There was no FAIL on the screen.

Comment: Oops. I made a typo in my previous comment... the parameter to insert is "nomodeset". Try that now.

Comment: Screen shows nothing!

Comment: @NimaRa time to reinstall Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

My Ubuntu hanged, so forcibly shutdown my PC and the result was Ubuntu was unable to log in to normal mode. Disk checking was not possible as / root partition was probably busy, and i was not able to umount as well as it displayed partition is busy. but the command came to my rescue was

> mount -o remount,rw /

followed by
sudo systemctl reboot

This should mount the root partition and boot normally.